# ¿Cómo guardar un DataFrame de Spark en memoria externe en formato CSV utilizando PySpark?

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark

Después de leer un *CSV* y cargarlo en un *DataFrame* de *Spark*, le he hecho algunas modificaciones. Ahora quiero guardar ese *DataFrame* modificado en la memoria de la pc en formato *CSV*. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer? Estoy usando *PySaprk*.

Encontré una forma de hacerlo con la siguiente línea de código:

```
dfX_String.write.csv("todo_String.csv", header = "true")
```

Lo que pasa es que no hace exactamente lo que quiero ya que, en vez de crear el archivo  *todo_String.csv*, lo que hace es crear un directorio *todo_String.csv* y dentro pone varios archivos entre ellos el *csv* pero con otro nombre.

Lo otro que me di cuenta es que las modificaciones que le hago al *DataFrame* no están cuando lo guardo. Me explico. Yo cargo un *CSV*:

```
dfX = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("inferSchema",True) \
    .option("header", True) \
    .load("inmune_X.csv")

dfX.printSchema()
```

Y todas las columnas son de tipo *Double*. Luego las cambio a *String* con este código:

```
 dfX_String = dfX.select(
  [dfX[c].cast(StringType())
   .alias(c) for c in dfX.columns]
)

dfX_String.printSchema()
```

Y sale que todas las columnas son de tipo *String*. Luego guardo este *DataFrame* con:

```
dfX_String.write.csv("todo_String.csv", header = "true")
```

Cuando cargo el *CSV* guardado:

```
df_String_Aux = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("inferSchema",True) \
    .option("header", True) \
    .load("todo_String.csv//df_String.csv")
df_String_Aux.printSchema()
```

Me dice que las columnas son de tipo *Double* y no *String* como supuestamente yo lo guardé